# Adjust type font and font size in mail with FPDF

Tags: php, html, email, fpdf

I need your help!

I have some file that generates a mail with attachment in FPDF and what I need is configure the font family for the mail to Arial and Size 12px, I know how to do that in the PDF but not in the mail.

This is the code for mail with FPDF

```
$filename = "example.pdf";
// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header (multipart mandatory)
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
$headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;
// message
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;
// attachment
$headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
$headers .= "--".$separator."--";
// send message
mail($to, $subject, "", $headers);
```

I hope you can help me, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Email needs to use inline styling, along the following lines:

```
<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px">This paragraph is formatted correctly</p>
```

Or you could put the style into a

```
<span>Here is lots of stuff.</span>
```

tag covering the relevant portions inside the

```
<body></body>
```

of the email.

I'm not sure why you are not putting $message as the third arg to mail() function. In any case, you will need to play with its content.